# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess

me estoy volviendo loco con el tema. He añadido una redirección a mi archivo htaccess y me ha empezado a salir ese error en los navegadores en la página principal. https://docentesdecentes.com/

He vuelto a dejar todo como estaba pero parece que el error se ha quedado para no irse. He probado a borrar caché y cookies pero persiste.
En cambio este enlace funciona bien -> https://docentesdecentes.com/index
No entiendo porque pasa si antes iba todo bien.
Os dejo por aquí parte de mi archivo htaccess a ver si veis algo que me pueda ayudar.
Gracias de antemano.

```
RewriteEngine on
# Diferenciar carpeta y archivo quitando  slash
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} recursos-educacion-infantil/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} recursos-educacion-primaria/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} recursos-generales/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} imagenes-sin-fondo/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} apps-y-webs-educativas/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 
#urls amigables
RewriteRule ^recurso/(.*)$ recurso.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog.php?slug=$1
RewriteRule ^apps-y-webs-educativas/para-alumnos/(.*)$ apps-y-webs-educativas/para-alumnos.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^recursos-educacion-primaria/curso-(.*)$ recursos-educacion-primaria/curso.php?curso=$1
RewriteRule ^recursos-educacion-primaria/asignatura-([^/]+)(/([^/]+))?$ recursos-educacion-primaria/asignatura.php?asignatura=$1&curso=$3
RewriteRule ^recursos-educacion-infantil/tema-(.*)$ recursos-educacion-infantil/tema.php?tema=$1
RewriteRule ^recursos-generales/tema-(.*)$ recursos-generales/tema.php?tema=$1
RewriteRule ^imagenes-sin-fondo/imagenesde/(.*)$ imagenes-sin-fondo/imagenesde.php?tema=$1
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /admin.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^avisos/(.*)$ /avisos.php?id=$1
# Quitar la extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
#para que no se pierdan los datos de formularios
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
## REDIRECCIONAR ##
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
## HTTP A HTTPS ##
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
## www to nonwww ##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.docentesdecentes.
RewriteRule ^ https://docentesdecentes.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Sugiero que renombres el archivo `.htaccess` del directorio root (que suele ser `public_html`). Luego intenta navegar a la página principal, deberá crearse un nuevo `.htaccess` limpio, el sitio debería funcionar. Ahora ve incorporando las redirecciones por pequeños bloques en el `.htaccess` nuevo (omitiendo las que ya hayan sido creadas) y probando en cada bloque añadido. Así podrás encontrar cual es la parte errónea en tus redirecciones.

Comment: Parece que estaba todo bien. Era cosa del caché del servidor.